# language learning game - how to categorize words in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I'm creating a language learning game, and for now am storing all vocab words in a JS object (for a concept, later I will store them in a database).

The words from the `words` object will be shown the player in a word bank. From there, they can click on a word to add it to the text box.

[image]

When they complete the sentence, they can submit, which will check the correct word order against a pre-written sentence. Something like:

`preWrittenSentence.push("Ni", "Hao", "Wo", "Shi");`

```
var correctOrder = preWrittenSentence.join(' ').toLowerCase();
if ($.trim(input.toLowerCase()) == correctOrder) {
    Good job...
```

In the game, if a player completes a "task", meaning they've submitted the correct sentence, they move on to the next task.

Originally, I structured the words by "task" in an object. This allowed me to only output the appropriate words for the given task to the word bank (otherwise, if I didn't separate them in the object, it would loop through every word in the object, even if it wasn't relevant for the given sentence):

```
var words = {
    "task1" :
    {
        'Ni'    : 'you',
        'Wo'    : 'I',
    },
    "task2" :
    {
        'Xie Xie' : 'Thanks',
        'Bu' : 'No',
    }
}
```

The problem with this is... If I want to reuse a word in another task, such as `Ni`, I would have to duplicate it in the object for that task... when I would rather just reuse `Ni` from task1.

So I thought maybe I can just lump all words into a object as such:

```
var words = {
    'Ni'    : 'you',
    'Wo'    : 'I',
    'Xie Xie' : 'Thanks',
    'Bu' : 'No'
}
```

But now I have no way to control which words I want displayed in the wordbank if they're all lumped together.

So finally, I thought maybe I can put words in the object by part of speech:

```
var words = {
    "pronouns" :
    {
        'Ni'    : 'you',
        'Wo'    : 'I',
    },
    "adjectives" :
    {
        'Hao'   : 'good',
        'Kuai'  : 'fast'    
    }
}
```

This would prevent duplication of words in the word database, but still wouldn't allow me to place the appropriate vocab in the word bank for the given task.

**So my question is:** is there a way to arrange it like the one above (`pronouns`, `adjectives`, etc) and select in an efficient way the words I would like displayed in the word bank given a certain task number?

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to interpret the string of every `key` and run a `sort` function beyond that. How many words are we talking about here?

Comment: @NicholasHazel thousands. but can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I would almost be tempted to make static `arrays` of your `pronouns`, `adjectives`, etc, and just organize it through them, and populate your dictionary with those.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code out and tell me if it fits your reqs.

```
var words = {
    pronouns :
        {
            Ni    : {
                text1    :    'you',
                text2    :    'Ni',
                tasks    :    '#1#2#3#'
            },
            Wo    : {
                text1    :    'I',
                text2    :    'Wo',
                tasks    :    '#3#4#'
            }
        },
    adjectives :
        {
            Hao    : {
                text1    :    'good',
                text2    :    'Hao',
                tasks    :    '#1#2#3#'
            },
            Kuai    : {
                text1    :    'fast',
                text2    :    'Kuai',
                tasks    :    '#2#4#'
            }
        }
};

function getWords(task) {
    var ret = new Array();

    for (var kind in words) {
        for (var word in words[kind]) {
            if (words[kind][word].tasks.match("#"+task+"#")) {
                ret.push(words[kind][word]);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

$(document).ready(new function(){
    var out = "";
    var arr = getWords(2);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var word = arr[i];
        out += "[" + word.text1 + "->" + word.text2 + "],";
    }
    alert(out);
});
```

I decided to put a little more complexity on your words, but...
The delimiters are configurable, of course ;)